# Charles proxy - how to use Map Local tool in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, charles-proxy

I use Charles in Firefox and now i decide to migrate to Chrome. In Firefox Charles autoconfiguration extension available and it works fine, but in Chrome Map Local don't work.
How to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should manually set proxy in Chrome to 127.0.0.1 with 8888 port to send requests through Charles.

Comment: Flushing that out. You go to Settings, click Advanced Settings, click Change Proxy Settings. That'll open your native system's network manager. From there find the place you can add a network proxy (in Ubuntu, for example, it's the Network Proxy entry, you change the method to "Manual". Enter 127.0.0.1 for the HTTP proxy (your local machine's address) and 8888 for the port (or whatever's listed in your .charles.config file under <port>). Apply that and browsing in Chrome while Charles Proxy is on will now record the headers if you have a session open.

Comment: my chrome already has these settings on mac, does that mean its already set up for use with charles?